# $f$ Riemann int; $\exists$ cont. fcn. $g$ s.t $\int |f(x)-g(x)| dx < \epsilon$. Show supp $g$ can be taken to be arbitrarily small nbhd of supp $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

> Suppose $f$ is a Riemann integrable function and for $\epsilon>0$, there is a continuous function $g$ so that $\int |f(x)-g(x)| \ dx < \epsilon$. Show that the support of $g$, $\text{supp } g$, can be taken to be an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the support of $f$, $\text{supp }f$.

Since we can make the integral of $|f-g|$ arbitrarily small, wouldn't this mean that the support of $f$ and support of $g$ are similar in size?

**How can we have support of $g$ be arbitrarily small inside the support of $f$?**

Comment: You say what we can make the integral arbitrarily small, do you mean the inequality holds for all $\epsilon$? if it does then the integral must be zero

Comment: We can make the integral arbitrarily close to $0$. How can we go from there to showing that support of $g$ can be taken to be an arbitrarily small neighborhood of support of $f$?

Comment: Think of $f(x)=\max(-|x|+1, 0)$ and $g(x)=f(x)+\max(-|x-a|+\varepsilon,0)$ for any real number $a$ with $|a|>1$ and $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small. This problem probably wants you to look closer at the result that the continuous functions approximate the integrable functions arbitrarily well.

Comment: What do you mean by neighborhood of a support? Neighborhoods are defined for a point. Do you mean that we can take $\operatorname {supp} g\subseteq \operatorname {supp} f$?

Comment: Also how do you measure the smallness of a support? I guess one approach is to use Jordan content, but I am not sure.

Comment: Outside the support of f we have $f(x)=0$. Hence, if we modify it by making it 0 outside supp (f) then we still have $\int |f-g| <\epsilon$. However we cannot just redefine g to be 0  on supp(f) because this may make g discontinuous. So we have to consider points whose distance to the complement of supp(f) is, say, less than $\epsilon /2$  and make g linear in small intervals. This is just the moral of the story being stated and not a solution.

Comment: If g is not $0$ on supp $f$, then how can supp $g$ be an arbitrarily small neighborhood of supp $f$?